# Doubt from Maximum principle Elliptic operator

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I was reading Maximum principal in PDE form Gilberg Trudinger

[image]

Remark
[image]

I do understand whole proof but i do not understand remark. I know that maxima of u  occure on $\partial \Omega^+$ but How maxima of u occur on $\partial \Omega$ i do not understand

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $u\in \partial \bar{\Omega}^+$ then either $u=0$ or $u\in \partial \Omega$.